# Class inheriting from dict but with element access

Tags: python, dictionary

I have classes that inherits from dict which look something like the following

```
class Instance(dict):
    def __init__(self, element, space):
        dict.__init__(self,
            Type='instance',
            Space=space,
            Element=element
    )
```

I've done this so that I can easily serialise them into a JSON format string. What I'd also like to be able to do is to expose the keys inside the dict as members on the derived type, so that I can do

```
Instance().Type
```

rather than

```
Instance['Type']
```

Is this possible and if so how can I do it?

Comment: Add Properties or implement `__getattr__`?

Comment: Why not just write a `to_dict` method on your object, instead of inheriting from `dict`? In this case, you wouldn't even need to. You could just use `vars(Instance())`

Comment: Some of the classes are composed of the other classes, so I need a generic solution. __getattr__ seems to work perfectly

Comment: Is there a special reason for not using pickle?

Comment: It's pretty trivial to write a `to_dict` method that handles composition. I think that inheriting from `dict` is not an ideal solution, but to each their own.